# how to make a drop down list for iphone application

Tags: iphone, xcode

I want to make a drop down list for iphone application i want that when user click it show list and when click on any button it shows that value and hides list i have implemented using the follwoing code but this work only for one value not for others

```
  @interface DropDownViewController : UIViewController {

IBOutlet UILabel*ddText;
IBOutlet UILabel*ddMenu;
IBOutlet UIButton*ddMenuShowButton;


  }

 @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *ddText;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *ddMenu;
 @property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *ddMenuShowButton;
 - (IBAction)ddMenuShow:(UIButton *)sender;
 - (IBAction)ddMenuSelectionMade:(UIButton *)sender;
 @end



 @implementation DropDownViewController
 @synthesize ddMenu, ddText;
 @synthesize ddMenuShowButton;

 - (IBAction)ddMenuShow:(UIButton *)sender
 {
    self.ddMenu.hidden = NO;
    [sender setTitle:@"▲" forState:UIControlStateNormal];


 }

 - (IBAction)ddMenuSelectionMade:(UIButton *)sender
{

 self.ddText.text = sender.titleLabel.text;
[self.ddMenuShowButton setTitle:@"▼" forState:UIControlStateNormal];


self.ddMenu.hidden = YES;

  }
```

I have three button red grenn blue first is red it works only for red only not for others how to solve this i have used this following this tutorial

http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/a-simple-drop-down-list-for-iphone/

Comment: You may want to post some more code or screenshots of your problem as its difficult to understand the issue.

Comment: problem is that as given tutoril when i press on red button it works but it does not work for other buttons

Comment: But you haven't implemented everything presented in the tutorial or the code you have pasted is incomplete.

Comment: I have also same as given but again that does not work

Comment: Then unless you put that part of code, hard to guess the cause.

Comment: Instead of this use UItableview to show dropdown.

Comment: @Madhmitha how to do like this any idea

Comment: just check that you have hooked blue and green to the method ddMenuSelectionMade and also you have set tags of buttons properly.

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467029/how-to-create-dropdown-in-xcode/18952583#18952583

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add UIbutton near your textfield.While clicking that button create UITableview according to your textfileld size.(Hope you know about creating Uitableview)and then load your listview contents in "cellForRowIndex".While selecting the row of the table,you can get the value from "didselectrowatIndexPath" and load it in textfield.After that remove UItableview.

Answer (score -2):

It would be good if you use iPhone tools in your application. You should use `UIPickerView` in the place of drop down list. It looks good and provides better interface in mobile application

Comment: its good i know but according to requirement i need to use drop down list

Comment: Pathetic people who want websites in their mobile app. If you are asking for mobile app then you should go with its tool not with website's tool.

Comment: you can can't say people about pathetic or else they will want as they will feel user friendly